# Using Javascript to axtract a SharePoint list value for filtering another list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a way to drill-down into SharePoint lists. My scenario is a SharePoint list of Clients and a SharePoint list of Engagements. The Engagements list contains a look-up back to Clients for filtering.

I have a Web-part page containing a view of the Clients list and another web-part page with a view of the Engagements list.

I want to select a Client on the Web-part page, capture the Client name in a variable, then build the URL to call the page with the Engagements for filtering.

I've found the code I need for creating the correct URL

I'm missing how I can pull the Client name from the selected item in the Client list to then build the URL.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome! It's not possible for us to help you with the level of detail you've included in your question. Can you please include some information about what you've already tried as well as some code?

Answer (score 0):

We can using the code below to monitor the item click event.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ms-listviewtable>tbody>tr .s4-itm-imgCbx").click(function(){
        var itemTitle=$(this).attr("title");
        console.log(itemTitle);
    });
});
</script>
```

To get the selected items, we need use JSOM code to achieve it.

```
function clickMethod() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var mySeletedItems = '';
    var i;
    for (i in items)
    {
        mySeletedItems += '|' + items[i].id;
    }
    alert (mySeletedItems);
}
```

If you want to get other fields from the selected item, we can get it using REST API base on the selected item Id. Then build the URL to filter another list.